# Query firebase nodes to get counts with dynamic paths

Tags: reactjs, typescript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm trying to figure out a more elegant way of doing this...

I am storing message objects and want to get the total number of conversations that have new messages. My node structure is like this:

`/messages/{userId}/{receipientId}/{messageId}/{message: '', senderId: '', status: 'new|read' }`

*** The messageId is an auto generated key from firebase. userId & receipientId are id's from auth.

The first code I wrote to get a number in the badge was this:

```
firebase.database().ref()
  .child(`/messages/${userId}/${receipientId}`)
  .orderByChild('status')
  .equalTo('new')
  .once('value')
  .then(innerSnapshot => {
    if (innerSnapshot.val() !== null) {
      if (newConversations.findIndex(item => item === entry) === -1) {
        newConversations.push(entry);
      }
    } 
  })
  .catch();
```

This requires me to wrap it in another query to get all of the receipientId's prior to running a separate query for each item found. It works...but is very brute-forcish.

Essentially, all I need to know is the number of receipientId nodes that has a "status: 'new'" entry somewhere under it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to query across multiple dynamic levels in your JSON, which is not possible with the Realtime Database. See [Firebase Query Double Nested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27207059/firebase-query-double-nested) and [Firebase query if child of child contains a value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40656589/firebase-query-if-child-of-child-contains-a-value).

As usual with NoSQL databases, consider modifying/augmenting your data structure to allow the use-case you want. So if you want to know the number of recipients that have a `status: 'new'`, consider storing precisely that: a top-level list of message recipients, with their message statuses. That pretty much the inverse data structure of what you have now, which is why it's somewhat of an inverted index.